# Modifying a large dynamically sized 3D array mex/C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, multidimensional-array, mex, dynamic-arrays

**Short Story:**  Trying to modify a large 3D array which gets allocated at run-time on the heap.  I believe the function that modifies the array, `vcross` shown below, is creating memory that doesn't get destroyed.

---

**Longer Story:**
I have a large 3D double array (~126000x3x3 or about 8.6MB) that I need to run some operations on.  I don't know how large the first dimension of this array is at compile time, so I allocate memory to the heap using the `new` and `delete` operations.

When I try to store values to this array, I get a segmentation violation.  This makes me think that while storing values to the array, I'm creating memory somewhere that goes to waste, and eventually fills up the heap.

The code compiles fine, but hits a seg violation when I run it.

```
static void inpolyh(
    double (*f)[3],//pointer to array[3], treated as 2D array where I don't know the first dimension until run-time.
    double (*v)[3],
    double (*p)[3],
    size_t numF,
    size_t numP)
{

    /*Calculate the baseNormals*/
    //allocate memory on the heap
    double (*baseNormals)[3] = NULL;//pointer to an array[3]
    if ( !(baseNormals = new double[numF][3]) ) { out_of_memory(); }

    //store the vector cross products in each array[3] of baseNormals
    for (int i=0; i<numF; i++) {
         vcross(baseNormals[i],
             v[(int)f[i][0]],
             v[(int)f[i][1]],
             v[(int)f[i][2]]);
         //THIS WORKS
    }

    /*Calculate face normals of tetrahedron*/
    //allocate memory on the heap (THIS WORKS)
    double (*faceNormals)[3][3] = NULL; //pointer to an array[3] of arrays[3]
    if ( !(faceNormals = new double[numP][3][3]) ) { out_of_memory(); }

    //store vector cross products into each array[3] of faceNormals
    for (int i=0; i<numP; i++ ) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++ ) {
            vcross(faceNormals[i][j],
                p[i],
                v[ (int) f[i][j] ],
                v[ (int) f[i][ (j + 1) % 3 ] ] );
            //SEG VIOLATION at i=37560
        }
    }

    delete [] baseNormals;
    delete [] faceNormals;
}
```

*This is where I believe the culprit to be.*  I think this function creates memory somewhere that never gets destroyed.  The vector cross product functions accepts four array[3] parameters and assigns some values to the first input parameter, which is passed by reference.

```
static void vcross(
    double (&n)[3],
    double a[3],
    double b[3],
    double c[3])
{
    n[0] = b[1] * c[2] - a[1] * c[2] + a[1] * b[2] - b[2]
                * c[1] + a[2] * c[1] - a[2] * b[1];
    n[1] = b[2] * c[0] - a[2] * c[0] + a[2] * b[0] - b[0]
                * c[2] + a[0] * c[2] - a[0] * b[2];
    n[2] = b[0] * c[1] - a[0] * c[1] + a[0] * b[1] - b[1]
                * c[0] + a[1] * c[0] - a[1] * b[0];
    return;
}
```

Other details that may matter:

- This is intended to be a mex function to run in matlab.
- Default Encoding: windows-1252
- MATLAB Root     : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b
- MATLAB Version  : 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7
- Processor ID    : x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
- Virtual Machine : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
- Window System   : Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Are there allocations in `vcross()` written in invisible ink?, because I can't see any.

Comment: In the `numP` loop, how sure are you that the `f` in `v[(int)f[i][(j+1)%3]]` has a greater or equal size then `numP`?  I suggest adding the line `assert(numF >= numP);` or something similar in your code.

Comment: It seems strange that you use double (casted to int) as index.

Comment: Oh goodness @ilent2, I think you just hit it on the head.  Good eye,  I'm going to re-evaluate what that index should be and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `(int)f[i][j]` is always in the range [0, <dimension of v>)? The first thing I'd do is to print out the values of `(int)f[i][j]` when the loop runs. Or just fire a debugger to see the values at the moment of the crash.

Comment: I generate the f and v arrays separately, which asserts that the indices given in f correspond to entries in v.